# Dropping linking R's from the middle of the words

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change

*Why does it exist and whom is it typical for? Is it the feature of the past century?*

I noticed Americans to do it. There are two examples coming to my mind, dated 1960s. The first one is the verse from the song ‘Moon River’: ***wherever*** you're going, I'm going your way. Frank Sinatra doesn't pronounce the first R in *wherever,* neither does Audrey Hepburn in *Breakfast at Tiffany's* — a British, but singing it in American way (it's at least about the -ing endings). The second example is Christopher Plummer (Captain von Trapp) in the film ‘The Sound of Music’ (figured it out that it's not him singing though, it's another American singer). He's singing the song *Edelweiss,* and the word ***forever*** is repeated many times in it. So he also says /faw evah/ every time.

Comment: Sometimes pronunciation in songs is a bit different because some sounds are easier to sing than others. Do you have any spoken examples?

Comment: @nnnnnn: unfortunately, I don't remember any. :(

Comment: _Forever_ can also be written as _for ever_ where (at least in British English) the 'r' isn't pronounced. In [this recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLxdb3ov-zE) where the word is sung several times at the end (starting about 2:26), the choir sings 'for ever' but the boy soloist does put the 'r' in.

Comment: Aw, they're just trying to sound erotic.

Comment: Actually, Plumber does pronounce the interior "R" -- it's just not that pronounced.  (And, no, I'm not making a joke, just using "pronounced" in a different sense.)

Comment: And Sinatra clearly pronounces both Rs.

Comment: @KateBunting: but even in this case the R links these two words together, doesn't it? For example, as in 'there is'.

Comment: @HotLicks: listen again, please: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJgGs9WpGt0 (31st second).

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy - Sinatra clearly pronounces both Rs in "wherever", even though he pretty much skips the second R in "breaker".  Do you know what an R sound is???

Comment: @HotLicks: I think I do. Well, now I hear the first R, but it's not a linking one, it's a rhotic R.

Comment: A careful singer will enunciate each word separately, even though most of us run words together in colloquial speech.

Comment: Frank Sinatra puts a **pause** between *where* and *ever* (I think because of how the music goes; I don't think he'd usually do this in speech). If you put a pause between two words, sometimes the linking /r/ is lost.

Comment: @PeterShor: thanks, I think you're right!

Answer (score 1):

In both "forever" and "wherever", I think there is some uncertainty as to whether we are dealing with one word or two.  Conventional spelling is not a certain guide, so just because the words are written with no space before "ever" doesn't tell us for sure.  Syllables in English end where words do, and r is lost at the end of syllables, if it's really "for ever" and "where ever", we'd expect r to be lost in a r-less dialect.  If it's really "forever" and "wherever", r should remain.

I suggest this is the source of the variation among singers and dialects.